# Автоматическое связывание файлов проекта на PHP

Tags: php

Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли как-то организовать автоматическое связывание файлов проекта на PHP? Дело в том, что накопилось уже порядка 100 файлов. И в каждом писать require_once на несколько каталогов вверх к другим папкам, а потом и там еще опускаться... В общем крайне неудобно это выходит. Либо, возможно, предложите еще какой-нибудь вариант? Мнение о существовании каких-то таких приемов возникло за счет того, что я смотрел примеры готовых проектов на PHP, но ни в одном из них не используются require/include. Как-то по-другому реализовано это.

И еще, подскажите, пожалуйста. Для обработчиков ошибок лучше создать единое пространство имен exceptions, либо на каждый свое? (обработчик ошибок с базой данных - одно пространство, обработчик ошибок с файлами - другое и так далее).

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. composer
2. Думаю, лучше использовать индивидуальные пространства имён, для эксепшенов